# Highcharts multiple dynamic panes with single legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts, panes

I would like to create a highchart with:
-Multiple panes that can be turned on and off to show different data streams (temperature, wind speed, wind direction)
-A single legend for each data stream where you can turn on and off different weather models (NAM, GFS, RAP)

Essentially the user could select, independently of each other, which data streams and which models to show.

To get the idea of what I mean you can see where I am at right now [here.](http://windypi.org/forecast.php) I would like there to be one legend, and when you turn off/on a data set all three graphs/panes respond, and also a selector where if you turned off Wind Speed, Wind Direction would slide upward/resize.
Any ideas? I was unable to even figure out how to make panes in highcharts so I understand if this is a pretty noob question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the highcharts you can use multiple axis like here:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

If you need to show/hide you should destroy / initialize new axis.

Customisation of legendItemClick: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I was able to get it working pretty smoothly, but I think the ability to pan time is going to bring me to highstock from highcharts.

Comment: It is only example, in the same way you can use panes in the highcharts.